# Does myristyl glucoside contain alcohol?

Tags: alcohols

I read that "myristyl glucoside is a product obtained by the condensation of myristyl alcohol with aglucose polymer." Does that mean that alcohol is part of the final product/myristyl glucoside itself? Or is all of the alcohol removed during the making of it?

Comment: The  myristyl alcohol becomes part of the final product by chemical reaction. Any excess will be removed by processing after the reaction.